# HashingVectorizer vs TfidfVectorizer export file size

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am generating a model using the below:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
text_clf = OnlinePipeline([('vect', HashingVectorizer()),
 ('clf-svm', SGDClassifier(loss='log', penalty='l2', alpha=1e-3, max_iter=5, random_state=None)),
])
```

When I export this model using the below:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(text_clf, 'text_clf.joblib')
```

My `text_clf.joblib` is 45MB. When I replace `HashingVectorizer()` with `TfidfVectorizer()` and re-export my model is 9kb.

Why is there such a file difference and is there anyway to reduce the size of the HashingVectorizer export.

Answer (score 2):

`HashingVectorizer` is stateless, so does not keep anything in memory. Its the number of features that are being passed from `HashingVectorizer` to the `SGDClassifier`.

By default the [number of features calculated from the data is](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html)

```
n_features=1048576
```

So, `SGDClassifier` will have to save `coef_`, `intercept_` etc variables for all these features. And this will increase if your problem is multi-class. For classes greater than 2, the storage will increase by number of classes times.

Need more details about `TfidfVectorizer` features. What is the size of `TfidfVectorizer.vocabulary_` in that case where its size is just 9kb? You can access that by:

```
len(text_clf.named_steps['vect'].vocabulary_)
```

Comment: Thanks. text_clf.named_steps['vect'].vocabulary is none. Are you aware of anyway to get the model down to ~5mb?

Comment: @Starchand Why is vocabulary none. Are you not fitting the tfidf-vectorizer?

Comment: seems not? I followed the tutorial at: https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-nlp-text-classification-using-scikit-learn-python-and-nltk-c52b92a7c73a

Comment: @Starchand Have you called `text_clf.fit()` or `text_clf.partial_fit()` after changing the `'vect'` to `TfidfVectorizer`?

Comment: sorry got that working. Im getting a length of 109. I did manage to get my model size down to 1mb with n_features=2 ** 15 inside HashingVectorizer which suits my needs and seems to still be giving a good accuracy

Comment: @Starchand Great.